# Simple way to add dictionaries in Python

Tags: python

I have a need to combine two dictionaries by adding the values of matching keys

```py
x = {'A': [1,2,3]}
y = {'A': [5,6]}

x+y # should be {'A': [1,2,3,5,6]}
```

Of course the above is not valid python code, but I feel I might be missing a feature if I implement this myself.

Here is a working implementation:

```py
def add_dicts(x1:dict, x2:dict)->dict:
    '''Combine two dictionaries, summing the values in keys that appear in both'''

    # Add the keys that appear in both dicts
    sum_of_matching_key_entries = {key: x1.get(key) + x2.get(key) for key in set(x1.keys()) & set(x2.keys())}

    # Union the dicts and overwrite the matching keys with the pre-computed sum
    return (x1|x2) | sum_of_matching_key_entries
```

but looking to see if I'm missing some language feature.

Comment: There's no built-in for this that I'm aware of.